# Current time in between two time

Tags: php, time, strtotime

This is my code to detect current time between `$time1` and `$time2`

```
$time1 = "1700";
$time2 = "0400";

if(intval($time1) > intval($time2))
{
    $open = strtotime("today " . $time1);
    $close = strtotime("tomorrow " . $time2);
}
else
{
    $open = strtotime("today " . $time1);
    $close = strtotime("today " . $time2);      
}
```

Ok what i am trying to do is to simulate something like car store opening time and closing time. basically, the car store opening and closing time is dynamic. let say the car store opens at 1400 and close at 0400 in the morning. so a customer visit the website at 0100, he should be able to see the car store is opened and not close. With my code, when customer visit at 0100, the car store is closed because the timer automatically makes it today the 1400 time. Is there any solution for the problem?

I am still learning and hopefully can guide me with my problems. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's `DateTime` objects:

```
<?php

$time1 = new DateTime("17:00");
$time2 = new DateTime("04:00");

if ($time2 < $time1) {
    $time1->modify("-1 day");
}

var_dump($time1, $time2);
```

Comment: `time1 : 2012-08-21 17:00:00`
`time2 : 2012-08-22 04:00:00`

`Current time: 2012-08-21 01:15:00`

supposedly, `time1` should be `2012-08-20 17:00:00` and `time2` should be `2012-08-21 04:00:00`

what should i adjust to make it like that? thanks for helping

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You want to check if the current date is between $time1 and $time2?

Comment: i have edited the post with latest explanation, sorry for the trouble

Comment: @user1594367: My code answers your requirements completely. If the second time is "earlier" than the first (but it should be later), add a day to it. That way, a customer coming at 1AM should see it opened. You cannot check to match against times without considering days.

Comment: no, because you see, the customer enters at 1 AM, the stime become 5 PM on that day itself, so i am thinking on how to make it as yesterday if customer enters at > 0000, your answer does exactly as my code. Any other advise/help? thanks

Comment: @user1594367: Yes, but what I've done is that if the second time is earlier than the first, you add a day to it. What you could try is to decrease a day from the first time instead. I've edited my answer. Try it now instead.

Comment: hmm, this wont work either because think about time before `stime` like let say 11am, the store will be open because the time is now is in yesterday